# Dropzone not adding image preview when adding image from code

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm trying to upload an image to `Dropzone` from code, so this image actually exists on the server, the image is loaded correctly but I can't see any preview. Infact, when I upload the image manually `Dropzone` create a new `<div>` which contains the following structure:

```
<div class="class="dz-preview-cover dz-image-preview">
     <image class="dz-preview-img" src="data:image/png;....." data-dz-thumbnail>
</div>
```

the `div` above is not  created when I add the image from code:

```
var blob = null
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", 'some url');
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function () {
    blob = xhr.response
    dz.files.push(blob);
    dz.emit("addedfile", blob);
    dz.emit("thumbnail", blob,  GlobalVariables.appUrl + '/assets/img/icons/default-image.png');
    dz.emit("complete", blob); 
}
xhr.send();
```

as I said the file is actually added, but the preview image not, am I missing something?